# Crystal report in visual basic using mysql database can't login to load report

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I can't login to mysql database to load the crystal report.
Everytime I load my report form, it asks for database login and shows this.

Database login windows shows :

```
server name : book_rentalDataset (I don't know why and it can't be changed)

database : (empty and can't be changed)

username :

password :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your database is not connecting with `VB Crystal Report` . To ensure this:

1. open your code in Visual Basics
2. Now move to ADD-Ins in the main menu
3. Then move to Visual Data Manager
4. VisData dialogue gets opened up . Go to Files
5. Select Open Databases
6. Select dataSource and enter your credentials
7. press ok to ensure if it is connected

   **You may also locate errors for the same by switching to** `File>Errors` .